# Custom Post types and Custom fields in Multisite

Tags: multisite

I'm new to Wordpress Multisite and I wonder if its possible to define a set of Custom Post Types (Films, Categories and Actors) and a set of Custom Fields (i.e. a Film has a trailer field, actors and a category) for every new site a make for the network.

I need to be able to create new sites and all of them must come preconfigured with the CPT and CF I said.

Is it possible with Wordpress MU or should I find another solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you place the CPT and fields code in a theme, each site in the network would be required to use that theme for the post type and custom fields to be available.  If, however, you place that code in a plugin and network activate the plugin, every site in your network can use a different theme and retain the custom post type and custom fields you require.